# permission denied to install mysql connector in linux mint with python version3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, mysql-connector, linux-mint

```
$ python setup.py install 
  running install
  Not Installing MySQL C Extension
  running build
  running build_py
  running install_lib
  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  writing requirements to lib/mysql_connector_python.egg-info/requires.txt
  error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'lib/mysql_connector_python.egg-info/requires.txt'
```

when i try to install mysql connector it shows an error when i execute the command "setup.py install".How can i overcome this error?

Comment: Don't know if it works but have you try sudo? Or ist the File opened by another programm?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run command with sudo.

sudo python setup.py install